# Bundling a file with a Phonegap app

Tags: android, ios, xml, file, cordova

I'm using Phonegap for developing my app. I used Backbone.js to implement my logic. I get XML files from the server and use the data in my app. This is the code responsible for it:

```
var CategoryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url:'http://www.someServer/someFile.xml',
  fetch: function(options) {
    options || (options = {});
    options.dataType = 'xml';
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
  },
  parse: function(data) {
    return $(data).find('someTag').map(function() {
      return {
        code:$(this).attr('code'),
        title : $(this).attr('title'),
        value : innerHtml
      };
    }).get();
  }
});
```

However, I need to find a way to make this XML data available locally upon installation, without requiring an internet connection. It's an app for tourists who may download the app when they're at home, but only run it when they're away from home, without internet access.

So I thought to use the [PhoneGap File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem), but I'm having difficulties understanding how it works and where I can place the files to have access to them the first time app runs.

Additionally, I would like the app to update the locally stored XML if the user has internet and the app detects that the server has a newer version of the XML file.

I'm open to any kind of solution to this problem such as `localStorage` or something else.

I'd really appreciate some suggestions!

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just drop the xml file in the assets folder in your phonegap app and access it as if you were accessing any web asset with a relative path (ie: `someFile.xml` rather than `http://www.someServer/someFile.xml`).

Comment: Yeah, right, but as I understood, I can't update file placed in assets folder. It's read only :(

Comment: Yup, that is correct you can't write to the assets folder but what you do is check to see if the file exists using the File API. If it doesn't use XHR to load the XML and then use the File API to write it to the location that you need. Then you'll be loading the file from the local file system and still able to update it by downloading a new file from the internet.